# Does my internet traffic get censored on a China Eastern flight?

Tags: air-travel, china, internet, connecting-flights, china-eastern

I'm going to Japan next summer, and the cheapest flight by far is 15 hours from where I am to Shanghai, a 4 hour layover (which I know will be censored), and a 3 hour flight to Tokyo (which doesn't have internet in the first place). Will I have to get a VPN if I want to do my normal internet use on the first flight?

Comment: Are you sure you will have internet access at all? I had a very similar flight plan to Japan with China Eastern and there was no Internet at all on board.

Comment: Most airlines, not just Chinese, operate some kind of content filtering to restrict bandwidth usage and transfer volume. I would not expect a VPN to work at all.

Comment: If this is a flight SFO-PVG or LAX-PVG, relax - there's no Internet on those flights at all unless they upgraded those planes in last six months.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo you can mask a VPN connection as TLS to get around pretty much any proxy detection system: http://blog.zorinaq.com/my-experience-with-the-great-firewall-of-china/

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Qantas has content filtering, but totally allows VPNs.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the sign in process on board is [very convoluted](http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2016/07/23/china-eastern-wifi/), so you may wish to familiarise yourself with that first, as it may require registering in advance ;)

However, from the same review:

> the typical “great firewall of China” also applies on China Eastern,
>   as you’d expect.

So yes, you will run into limitations.